# SceneKit CALayer unsharp drawing

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, scenekit, cashapelayer

I'm trying to draw UIBezierPaths and display them on a SCNPlane, though I'm getting a very unsharp result [(See in the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCv6z.jpg)  How could I make it sharper?

```swift
let displayLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  displayLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
  displayLayer.path = path.cgPath
  displayLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
  displayLayer.strokeColor = stroke.cgColor
  displayLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
  let plane = SCNPlane(width:size.width, height: size.height)
  let material = SCNMaterial()
  material.diffuse.contents = displayLayer
  plane.materials = [material]
  let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
```

I've tried to increase the displayLayer.frame's size but it only made things smaller.

Thanks for your answer! 
Andras

Comment: changing the layer's frame is a good idea because it will lead to a larger texture to map the object. You'll need to scale the Bézier path by the same amount for it to appear of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been driving me crazy, so hopefully this answer helps someone else who stumbles across this. I'm mapping a `CALayer` to a `SCNMaterial` texture for use in an ARKit scene, and everything was blurry/pixelated. Setting the `contentsScale` property of the `CALayer` to `UIScreen.main.scale` didn't do anything, nor playing with `shouldRasterize` and `rasterizationScale`.

The solution is to set the layer's frame to the desired frame, multiplied by the screen's scale, otherwise the material is scale transforming the layer to fit the texture. In other words, the layer's size needs to be 3x its desired size.

`let layer = CALayer()
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500 * UIScreen.main.scale, height: 750 * UIScreen.main.scale)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change UIBezierPath "flatness" property (0.1, 0.01, 0.001 etc).

Comment: Thanks, but sadly didn't work, I'm having trouble with the rendering I guess.